# how to dynamically access a function(created by a factory) via its identifier name in module instead of its name in closure

Tags: python

#### How could i access the identifier name of a function instead of its name in closure by string match?

I have a module named `tool_factory.py`

```py
def factory(config):
   def f(*arg, **kwargs):
      ...
   return f
   
func_1_tool = factory(config.a1) # 
func_2_tool = factory(config.a2) #
```

At another file `consumeit.py` that `comsume` the module ,try to get `tool` like function, i.e `func_1_tool`, `func_2_tool`

```py
import inspect
import tool_factory as tool_module
istool = lambda member: inspect.isfunction(member) 
         and member.__name__.endswith('_tool') # not work cause __name__ = 'f'
tools = inspect.getmembers(tool_module, istool) 

# call the tools
```

I have tried using decorators via functools.wraps. But for some scenes, `factory` is straight-foward , simple, shorter( `one-line` style)

## updates

I had a workround aproach to recoganize these functions, it's more concise to find them,but i don't like the trick that hide the purpose

```py
# ugly maybe
lambda member: ... and member.__qualname__ == 'factory.<locals>.f'
```

Is there better solution or any advice ?

Comment: For code-generate purpose, Sorry for contextless

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect to happen? What should be the result/value of ``tools``? Is there any reason why you don't just store a list/dict/... of tools when creating them?

Comment: I am doing code-generation. which has generated some `tool` function there already. but the job needs run next time, that's why I check the existed ones not to overwrite them

Comment: By far the best way to go about this would be to change how the `tool_factory` module works. You could manually add the tools to a list with something like `tools = [func_1_tool, func_2_tool]`. Or you could even just change the factory function to stick all the things it creates into a list somewhere (e.g. add `tools = []` up top, then put `tools.append(f)` just before the `return f` line).

Comment: `inspect.getmembers()` simply isn't the appropriate thing to use here - you want to filter the module's contents based on their names, but `getmembers()` has no such option.  Try `for name, member in tool_module.__dict__.items():` - you can then check `member` for being a function, and `name` for ending with "_tool".

Comment: @Blckknght It's very kind of you. That's good for managerment. But the code-gen job still get a way to find which one has been generated by its name, even it knows the list and its length. Can the factory function know the left-side identifier and its name?

Comment: @ jasonharper, It works,thank you. I have lost in the special variables world:)

Comment: Ah, no, the factory wouldn't know what variable it's return value is going to be assigned to. But that's sort of the point. Those variable names shouldn't be data, you should instead *always* use a container data structure, rather than numbered variables. If the names only differ by a number (like `func_1_tool` and `func_2_tool`) you should probably be using a list, and indexing with the number (or a slightly different number, since you need to start at index 0). If you need to map from an arbitrary string to a value, use a dictionary!

Answer (score 0):

## It isn't actually a case that `getmembers() work for.

Here is the answer refer to `jasonharper`'s comment

```py
name, member in tool_module.__dict__.items(): 
    #can then check member for being a function, and name for ending with "_tool".
```